# NSNumberFormatter with 2 decimal points results in strange result

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to convert a float value to string and use the NSNumberFormatter. I made a rounding function and use the formatter for string representation. The formatter should only do the locale and decimal symbol. I end up with a wrong value. The result of

```
NSNumberFormatter *_numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[_numberFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"]];
[_numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[_numberFormatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
NSString* sumString = [_numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:14.2f]];
```

is '14,19'. I don't understand why the value is rounded down when the decimal point is just 1 here. The rounding mode should do nothing here or am I wrong. I could use 'NSNumberFormatterRoundUp' but maybe the result will be '14,21' in some case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that a base-2 floating-point number (which is what all Apple platforms use) cannot exactly represent the real number 14.2. The closest double-precision floating-point number is exactly 14.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875. As you can see, this is slightly less than 14.2.

You specified the `NSNumberFormatterRoundDown` rounding mode. This means that the formatter will print the largest number that conforms to your format (two fractional digits) and is less than or equal to the input number. The largest decimal number with two fractional digits that is less than or equal to 14.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875 is 14.19.

You might want to look at `NSDecimalNumber` if you are dealing with monetary values. `NSDecimalNumber` is much slower than `double`, but it is a base-10 floating-point format, so it can represent 14.2 exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `NSNumberFormatterRoundDown` with `NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp`.

`NSNumberFormatterRoundDown`:
Round towards zero.

`NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfDown`:
Round towards the nearest integer, or towards zero if equidistant.